# How to update an existing excel file using java program?

Tags: java, object-oriented, programming-practices, file-handling

I've made a file browser in java that opens and read already been made excel files. (using Apache poi 3.9 library)
program read those files perfectly but i want to update some of those files. how can i be able to update those files through my program.
is there is any library or function/class that might be helpful, or also any other language that can support that feature (among c/c++, python)..???

Comment: AFAIK Apache POI supports changing Excel files as well as reading, so where is your problem?

Comment: right now i've to first open a file then read cells then creat another workbook, copy data from first file to that workbook then write 2nd workbook into the first one.... (is this an efficient way..??? I don't think so)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue with Apache POI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of examples on the Apachi POI library site on how to change and save Excel files. Here are a couple of pages to get you started:

- [Apache POI Spreadsheet HOWTO - The New Halloween Document](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html)
- [Apache POI Spreadsheet Quick Guide - Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

E.g. workbook objects in the library have a [`write(…)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) method if you want to save the contents of it to a file using an appropriate `OutputStream`:

```
// Save a workbook (wb)
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("my_workbook.xls");
wb.write(out);
out.close();
```

If you want to open the files in Excel you can, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978369/java-run-excel-using-runtime-getruntime-exec), try using `Desktop` which is available in JDK6.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\file.xls"));
```

Comment: Thanks for response Spoike but i don't want to creat extra workbooks i just want to open one show that one to the user and let the user to change it. just like we did in Ms Excel.

Comment: @haseebAkhtar Wouldn't it be better to open the file in Excel from your Java program?

Comment: could you explain please....? (Help me how)

Comment: @haseebAkhtar You can use `Desktop` to open files with appropriate program. I.e. it assumes that Excel is installed in the user's computer and that the extension is correctly associated with Excel.

Comment: Thats cool, thanks for giving me SucH a HelPfuL information.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If POI is not sufficient for any kind of reasons, you may have to utilize Excel by using COM Automation for such a task. Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679810/is-there-ole-automation-in-java) for more information how to do this in Java. But beware, this will have some drawbacks:

- platform-dependent (will only work on Windows)
- won't work well for a server-side application
- slow (compared to direct access by POI)

Comment: This is something \m/